# prove a theorem - geometry

Tags: geometry

I have been trying to prove this theorem, but can't solve it. Can anyone help me?

For any convex quadrilateral, in which M and N are the midpoints of the diagonals, the following relationship about the sides is true.

AB<sup>2</sup>+BC<sup>2</sup>+CD<sup>2</sup>+DA<sup>2</sup>=AC<sup>2</sup>+BD<sup>2</sup>+4MN<sup>2</sup>

[image]

Comment: Certainly $M$ and $N$ have to be in some special configuration -- they can (in theory) be moved freely so that the length $MN$ changes without changing any of the other lengths. What that configuration is, I have no idea...

Comment: That is my problem. There is nothing said about the MN. Has anyone heard of this theorem?

Comment: take a square as example and see what M and N may be..maybe the halves?

Comment: This is true only if M and N are the midpoints of the diagonals.

Comment: FYI: In [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1616600/409), I interpret the result (where $M$ and $N$ are midpoints of the diagonals) as one about edges of a *tetrahedron*, and I prove the counterpart in hyperbolic non-Euclidean space.

Comment: When the quadrilateral is a parallelogram, then $M=N$ and we get the usual formula for the sum of the squares of the diagonals of the parallelogram.

Comment: Great question! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

This is perhaps not the most insightful proof, but vector methods are often very powerful. Put $A$ at the origin, and let $\vec x = \overrightarrow{AB}$, $\vec y = \overrightarrow{AD}$, and $\vec z = \overrightarrow{DC}$. Then the left-hand side is
$$\|\vec x\|^2 + \|\vec y\|^2 + \|\vec z\|^2 + \|\vec x-(\vec y+\vec z)\|^2,$$
whereas the right-hand side is
$$\|\vec y+\vec z\|^2 + \|\vec y - \vec x\|^2 + 4\|\tfrac12(\vec y+\vec z) - \tfrac12(\vec x+\vec y)\|^2.$$
Expanding, and using $\|\vec u+\vec v\|^2 = \|\vec u\|^2+\|\vec v\|^2 + 2\vec u\cdot \vec v$, we see that the two expressions are equal.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right claim - M and N are midpoints.

[image]

Comment: In what way is this an answer to the question?

Comment: It seems that the question has been edited after I made the diagram, specifying M and N as midpoints.